# ASP.NET ItemTemplate Container.DataItem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I have a Repeater on one of my pages like so:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrHalls" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Choose_Hall">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn<% Container.DataItem %>" runat="server"
        CommandName="<% Container.DataItem %>" Text="<% Container.DataItem %>"
         />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But, when I run it it errors out with the message:

> 'btn<% Container.DataItem %>' is not a valid identifier.

I want to append btn to the Container.DataItem value so that I have dynamically assigned control names that are associated with the underlying data item. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like

```
 <asp:Button ID='<%# "btn" + Container.DataItem %>'  runat="server"
```

and depends on the type of Container.DataItem

but is there a reason why you want to set the ID and not use something like this ?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit"  runat="server"
```

Comment: The dataitem is just a string.

Comment: I guess I could do that...I just thought it would be nice to have each one named specifically after the value in DataItem rather than a generic button name.

Comment: ah ok. keep in mind it would still append something like myRepeater$ctl00 to the ID when rendered.